# How to fix some physics bodies behavior, when some bodies go off the physics edges?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skphysicsbody

I am working with a game, which has a physics world. I create physics box around the whole scene for prevent the sprites go off the screen. But the issue is, when i add too many bodies to the scene, some of them go off this physics box. 
This is the physics box around the scene:

```
    homeArea.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)
    homeArea.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.frame.size.height / 2.0)
    homeLayer.addChild(homeArea)

    homeArea.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: CGRectMake(-homeArea.frame.width / 2.0, -homeArea.frame.height / 2.0, homeArea.frame.size.width, homeArea.frame.size.height))
```

This is these too many bodies:

```
func addSprites() {
    for i in 0...20 {
        for j in 0...20 {
            let shape = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRectMake(-5.0, -5.0, 10.0, 10.0))
            shape.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()
            shape.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width - (shape.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i)), 0.0 + (shape.frame.size.height * CGFloat(j)))
            shape.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: shape.frame.size)
            shape.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            addChild(shape)
        }
    }
}
```

And i create a cannon shooting to these bodies. There i want to create something like splash from cannon's bullet. I shoot to this wall from sprites, and notice from nodes count, that because of my bullet, some sprites go off the screen. I added the method usesPreciseCollisionDetection. But it's all the same.

Comment: The physics is built for speed, not accuracy.  You may need to create an alternative method to get around this issue.

Comment: So i have to write some method, which would calculate the behavior of all sprites, and do not use physics engine of spritekit? Am I right?

Comment: no, you can use the physics engine, but if you have too many things going on in the physics, things will break.  So you may have to do things like using a particle engine, or divide up the categories so that less checks are being done